# Install4j Md5Checker: could not get md5sums

Tags: install4j

I got the below error when executing DownloadFileAction in auto update

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.net.DownloadFileAction [ID 63]: Started action at 2017-03-09T14:09:55
       Execute action
       Property checkForMd5Sums: true
       Property retryIfInterrupted: true
       Property dontAskForRetry: true
       Property showFileName: true
       Property showProgress: true
       Property md5Url: 
       Property targetFile: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents\xx_Windows_1_6_1.exe
       Property deleteOnExit: false
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property showError: true
       Property connectTimeout: 10000
       Property readTimeout: 20000
       Property askForProxy: true
       Property connectionFailureScript: null
       Property acceptAllCertificates: true
       Property requestHeaders: []
       Property url: https://10.1.0.142:8080/download/dc/xx_Windows_1_6_1.exe
       Backing up C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents\xx_Windows_1_6_1.exe
       Download: https://10.15.0.142:8080/download/dc/xx_Windows_1_6_1.exe to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Documents\xx_Windows_1_6_1.exe; size: 250728960 bytes
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Md5Checker: could not get md5sums
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.net.DownloadFileAction [ID 63]: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.15.0.142 found
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.15.0.142 found
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
```

Please guide me to resolve the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in install4j 6.1.5 that will be fixed in 6.1.6. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.